# Как работает экранирование в литерале регулярного выражения JS?

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения, webstorm

Узнал про литералы `regexp` в JS и решил попробовать. Насколько я понимаю, отличий между написанием регулярного выражение как строки и как литерала всего три:

- В литерале не требуется дополнительного экранирования слэшей `//`
- Литерал неизменяем
- В литерале можно использовать дополнительные опции *(например буква g, которая задаёт глобальный поиск)*

И вот у меня была регулярка:

```js
const regexp = '\\[[^\\[\\]]*\\]';
let str = '[image|variant][image|variant][image|variant]';
let results = [...str.matchAll(regexp)];
alert(results[0]);
```

И я решил поменять её на такой литерал: `/\[[^\[\]]*\]/g`. Он корректно работает, но WebStorm почему-то настойчиво предлагает мне удалить экранирование для последней квадратной скобки. Я попробовал, и такой вариант тоже работает: `/\[[^\[\]]*]/g`.

Почему последнюю квадратную скобку можно не экранировать? Есть ли какие-то чёткие правила по этому поводу?

**UPD:** Любопытно, что это работает только с квадратными скобками. Я решил проверить, можно ли не экранировать последнюю скобку, если она будет круглой: `/\([^\[\]]*)/g`, но такой литерал не валиден и вызывает ошибку.

Comment: Вы ещё можете удалить экранирование открывающей квадратной скобки внутри класса символов. Некоторые правила экранирования в классах можно посмотреть тут: https://javascript.info/regexp-character-sets-and-ranges#escaping-in- К сожалению, там, кажется, ничего нет про ваш случай.

Comment: Хотя вот тут из перечисления спецсимволов для экранирования можно сделать вывод, что закрывающая квадратная скобка вообще не нуждается в экранировании (если она вне класса, как будет указано отдельно в правилах экранированя в классах): https://javascript.info/regexp-escaping

Comment: @vsemozhebuty ну да, там приводится список символов, среди них нет закрывающей квадратной скобки, а закрывающая круглая есть: `[ \ ^ $ . | ? * + ( ).` Но в моём случае квадратные скобки как символы используются два раза. И из-за этого первую закрывающую скобку всё-таки приходится экранировать: `/\[[^\[\]]*]/g`. Вот так не получится, это уже будет другим выражением: `/\[[^\[]]*]/g`

Comment: Да, потому что одна закрывающая скобка у вас внутри класса, а другая нет. Поэтому первую нужно экранировать, чтобы было понятно, где закрывается класс, а вторую — нет.

Comment: @vsemozhebuty ага, точно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@vsemozhebuty` привел [ссылку](https://javascript.info/regexp-escaping), в которой содержался ответ на вопрос. Начать следует с того, что там приводится список специальных символов, используемых в `regexp`:

> Есть и другие специальные символы, которые имеют особое значение в
> регулярном выражении. Они используются для более эффективного поиска.
> Вот полный список из них: `[ \ ^ $ . | ? * + ( ).`

Следует обратить внимание, что закрывающей квадратной скобки `]` в этом списке нет, зато есть закрывающая круглая скобка `)`, что отвечает на мой вопрос о том, почему закрывающую квадратную скобку не надо экранировать, а круглую надо.

Однако в моём `regexp` комбинация из квадратных скобок как символов используется дважды:

```
/\[[^\[\]]*]/g

// последняя квадратная скобка не экранирована (3 символ справа)
// другую закрывающую квадратную скобку приходится всё так же экранировать (6 символ справа)
```

И квадратную скобку, которая идёт шестым символом справа, приходится по-прежнему экранировать, иначе она начинает считаться не скобкой-символом, а управляющей скобкой, которая закрывает диапазон. Конкретно про такую ситуацию по ссылке ничего нет, но в данном случае нужда в экранировании выглядит логично *(иначе интерпретатор просто неверно истолкует `regexp`)*.

**P.S.:** Сначала я решил, что это просто причуды JS, этот язык очень любит меня удивлять. Но, оказывается, ситуация с закрывающей квадратной скобкой `]` является нормальной для регулярных выражений вообще, а не только в JS. По крайней мере так мне говорит [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/IY2AXE/1). Это забавно.

Answer (score 1):

Потому что нет открываючей (`[`) квадратной скобки:

[image: RegExp]

Comment: А самая первая открывающая скобка? Третий символ слева? Да, она экранирована, потому что она нужна мне именно как символ, но она есть. То есть парсер сам понимает, что раз открывающей нет, а закрывающая есть, то это просто символ, а не специальный символ?

Comment: Просто я попробовал вот такое выражение: `/\([^\[\]]*\)/g` . Поменял квадратные скобки на круглые *(которые тоже являются спецсимволами)*. Экранировал первую скобку, но WebStorm заставляет экранировать и вторую скобку тоже.

Comment: @Zhenyria, по первому комменту — скорее всего так и есть; по второму — не знаю; нужно гуглить, анализировать, etc ... Я думал, что и с круглыми так.